# How does this sound? Sessions & Cookies?

Tags: session, cookies, session-hijacking

Cookies and sessions both have pros and cons. But I was thinking, how about when a user logs in it creates a session with their username and password in, but when they register they get given a unique 'access token'.

So when they login it will create a cookie with their access token in and a session with their username and password.

I will then scan the database for a user with the username and password in the sessions, and the access token in the cookie.

I was hoping this would prevent session hijacking.

Comment: please do everyone a favor and click the grey checkmark next to Corbin's answer, so that we all know that this question has been answered. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would not.  Sessions are basically tokens in a cookie, so all your doing is making a second token have to be stolen.  If someone can steal one, they can steal two.  I suggest you google around for strategies of preventing session hijacking.